# How to show JPanel from a JFrame from another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, visible

So I tried displaying my other JFrame from this JFrame using the method setVisible(true)

However, the JPanel of that JFrame did not show up

this is for our school project THANKS YOUUUUUU

Comment: The Stack Overflow question [The Use of Multiple JFrames: Good or Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice) goes over the pros and cons of using multiple JFrames.  Unless you post a [mre] by editing your question, we can't help you.

Comment: I'd guess the hand-in time for that school project has now passed. A tip for the future, you might have got more than 3 views in the more than a month it has been posted if you add relevant tags many people watch, like [tag:java] and [tag:swing].